# TCL Script - expect when scp is done

Tags: scp, expect

I currently have a tcl script that is sending a .tar.gz to a remote server.

```
spawn scp -r "file_to_send.tar.gz" $user@$host:/
set timeout 10

spawn ssh $user@$host
expect "password: "
send -- "$passwd\r"

send -- "tar -zxvf /file_to_send.tar.gz\r"
sleep 1
```

However, it seems like my extract doesn't work because the scp didn't fully complete. Is there a way to programmatically check when the scp is complete?

Comment: Can that comment be completed in 10 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for the first spawn to finish by following it with

```
expect eof
```

or if you prefer you can capture and test the return code

```
catch wait result
if [lindex $result 3] { send_user "fail\n";  exit 1 }
send_user "ok\n"
```